# Custom Repository (REQUEST DQL)

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have an error when I would like to add a custom method with DQL Request.
Error:

> Undefined method 'getAll'. The method name must start with either
>   findBy or findOneBy!

**My Controller:(SheetController.php)**

```
<?php
namespace Test\FrontBundle\Controller;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityNotFoundException;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Test\FrontBundle\Entity\Sheet;

class SheetController extends Controller
{
    public function sheetListAction(Request $request)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $repository = $em->getRepository('TestFrontBundle:Sheet');

        $sheets = $repository->getAll();
        var_dump($sheets);
        return $this->render('TestFrontBundle:Sheet:sheetList.html.twig');
    }
    public function sheetAction($id, Request $request)
    {
        $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('TestFrontBundle:Sheet');
        $sheet = $repository->find($id);
        if(!$sheet)
        {
            throw new EntityNotFoundException();
        }
        return $this->render('TestFrontBundle:Sheet:sheet.html.twig', array('sheet' => $sheet));
    }
}
?>
```

**My Repository:(SheetRepository.php)**

```
<?php

namespace Test\FrontBundle\Entity;

/**
 * SheetRepository
 *
 * This class was generated by the Doctrine ORM. Add your own custom
 * repository methods below.
 */

class SheetRepository extends \Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
{
    public function getAll()
    {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('s');

        $query = $qb;

        $result = $query->getQuery()->execute();

        return $result;
    }
}
```

Please, Could you help me? :)

Comment: You need to add the location of your repository to your entity mapping. `@ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="...")`. Check if yours is configured.

Comment: Hi, Yes it is. On Entity/Sheet.php I have (`/**
 * Sheet
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Test\FrontBundle\Entity\SheetRepository")
 */)`

Comment: Thanks Artamiel ! Yes I forget to put " `@ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Test\FrontBundle\Entity\SheetRepository `") in my repository ! Thanks you a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use native Doctrine query findAll() for this?

```
public function sheetListAction(Request $request)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $repository = $em->getRepository('TestFrontBundle:Sheet');

    $sheets = $repository->findAll();
    /***/
}
```

EDIT - With class repository:

```
class SheetRepository extends \Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
{
    public function getAll()
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('s')
           ->select('s')
           ->getQuery()
           ->getResult()
       ;
    }
}
```

And in your controller : replace `findAll()` by `getAll()`

Comment: Because I would like to "add" my first custom method ^^' I'm learning Symfony2 and it's my first try to "add" a method :s But I know "findAll" have the same impact by I would like to try DQL.

Comment: @scoolnico - You don't need to put all that logic in `getAll()` of `SheetRepository`. You can just call `$this->findAll();` in `getAll()` method.